# Script does not save output to correct path while using auto py to exe

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, netsh, auto-py-to-exe

my program uses netsh to save wifi profile information on a txt file in a directory that is named as the system time of the moment of running the program

so lets say you have signed into three wifi networks on your PC:

Wifi1:
password:123456
wifi2:
password: abcdefg
wifi3:
password: 12456!

and the py file path is:

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Pp

and the system time is:

2024-01-23 16;51;44.894633

the output should be three txt files saved to directory:

c:\Users\User\Desktop\Pp\2024-01-23 16;51;44.894633

this works when i just run the python program through VScode, but i wanted to be able to make it an executable with auto py to exe

the problem is that it saves the txt to a different directory ONLY when i use the exe file. so when i open the exe file the path will be three txt files saved to this path:

saved to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI124562\2024-01-23 16;51;44.894633

in short it doesnt save the files to the correct path ONLY when using the .exe file, but it works correctly when i run the .py file.

python code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
names_string = os.popen("netsh wlan show profile")

names_list = []
for i in names_string:
    if ":" in i:
        names_list.append(i[i.index(":") + 2:len(i) - 1])
    else:
        next

foldername = f"{datetime.now()}"
folder_name = foldername
folder_name = folder_name.replace(":", ";")
parent_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = os.path.join(parent_path, folder_name)
os.mkdir(path)

for i in names_list:
    with open (path + f"/{i}.txt", 'w') as fp:
        print("saved to", path + f"/{i}.txt")
        output = os.popen(f"""netsh wlan show profile name = "{i}" key = clear""").read()
        fp.write(output)

input("press enter to close window")
```

auto py to exe output:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.42.0
Building directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Pp/main.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console C:/Users/User/Desktop/Pp/main.py --distpath C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq\application --workpath C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq\build --specpath C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq

21259 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.3.0
21263 INFO: Python: 3.12.1
21302 INFO: Platform: Windows-11-10.0.22621-SP0
21316 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq\main.spec
21332 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Pp']
21955 INFO: checking Analysis
21969 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
21984 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
22003 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
22083 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
23851 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
23871 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
27590 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
31066 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
31219 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
31223 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
31243 INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.dll
31250 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\User\Desktop\Pp\main.py
31270 INFO: Processing module hooks...
31282 INFO: Performing binary vs. data reclassification (2 entries)
31302 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
31315 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
31338 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
31363 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
31552 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): []
31558 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): []
31870 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
31887 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq\build\main\warn-main.txt
31919 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq\build\main\xref-main.html
31990 INFO: checking PYZ
31994 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
32005 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
32311 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
32336 INFO: checking PKG
32351 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
32355 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg
34491 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg completed successfully.
34521 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\run.exe
34528 INFO: checking EXE
34537 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
34550 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
34566 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_xeexcq\application\main.exe
34754 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
34865 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
34884 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
35011 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
35036 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
38225 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

Moving project to: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Pp\output
Complete.
```

i tried to reinstall auto py to exe multipul times, i tried disabling windows defender (as it has a pop up every time i use auto py to exe) and my antivirus, tried on two different pcs just for it to not work, i tried reinstalling python twice.and i havent found any useful information online.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import sys

exe_path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
exe_dir = os.path.dirname(exe_path)


names_string = os.popen("netsh wlan show profile")

names_list = []
for i in names_string:
    if ":" in i:
        names_list.append(i[i.index(":") + 2:len(i) - 1])
    else:
        next

foldername = f"{datetime.now()}"
folder_name = foldername
folder_name = folder_name.replace(":", ";")
path = os.path.join(exe_dir, folder_name)
os.mkdir(path)

for i in names_list:
    with open (path + f"/{i}.txt", 'w') as fp:
        print("saved to", path + f"/{i}.txt")
        output = os.popen(f"""netsh wlan show profile name = "{i}" key = clear""").read()
        fp.write(output)

input("press enter to close window")
```

Comment: It works! thank you so much!

but why? if you could provide an explanation i would appriciate it very much!

Comment: When you create an .exe file with PyInstaller and run it, it executes in the \AppData\Local\Temp... directory, so the program will save the files to this directory, which was what you encountered. `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])`  gets the absoulte path of the script. `os.path.dirname(exe_path) `  creates a directory with the absoulte path of the script (exe). I hope this makes sense, let me know if it doesn't